SQL query times out when ROWNUM column added to it
I have the first query that works. But then I added ROWNUM column to try to paginate the results. Now it seems to just times out without returning any results. Do not understand the issue here on the Oracle database.
// Working
select 
    tablea.* 
from 
    (select 
         vcell.operator_name, vcell.vendor_name, 
         v_territory.territory_label as Region, 
         v_zone.zone_short_name as Zone, v_cluster.cluster_nm, 
         vcell.engineering_number, v_location.loc_site_long_nm as Name,
         vcell.Band infoband, vcell.Freq_Band infofreqband, 
         vcell.Carrier infocarr, vcell.channel_bandwidth infobandwidth, 
         vcell.cell_type infocelltype, vcell.enodeb_id infoenbid, 
         vcell.local_cell_id infocellid, vcell.ecell_name infocellname, 
         vcell.Sector infosector, vcell.Channel infochannel,
         vcell.physical_cell_id infopci, vcell.TAC infotac, 
         tbl.* 
     from
         cim.v_zone v_zone, cim.v_cluster v_cluster, 
         cim.v_territory v_territory, cim.v_location v_location,
         cim.v_cell_lte vcell, netact_b_lnd.SRAN_CELL_LNCEL tbl 
     where
         v_zone.zone_label = '9' 
         and v_location.operator_name = 'Base' 
         and vcell.operator_name = 'Box' 
         and vcell.vendor_name = 'N' 
         and v_zone.zone_id = v_cluster.zone_id 
         and v_territory.territory_id = v_zone.territory_id 
         and v_cluster.cluster_id = v_location.cluster_id 
         and vcell.engineering_number = v_location.engineering_number 
         and SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNBTS-',1) + 6, 6) = vcell.enodeb_id
         and REPLACE(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, 'LNCEL-', 1) + 6, INSTR(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME || '/', INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, 4),'/',1)),'/','') = vcell.local_cell_id 
       order by tbl.distname) tablea

// Not working
select 
    tablea.*, ROWNUM 
from 
    (select
         vcell.operator_name, vcell.vendor_name, 
         v_territory.territory_label as Region, 
         v_zone.zone_short_name as Zone, v_cluster.cluster_nm, 
         vcell.engineering_number, v_location.loc_site_long_nm as Name,
         vcell.Band infoband, vcell.Freq_Band infofreqband, 
         vcell.Carrier infocarr,vcell.channel_bandwidth infobandwidth, 
         vcell.cell_type infocelltype, vcell.enodeb_id infoenbid, 
         vcell.local_cell_id infocellid,vcell.ecell_name infocellname,
         vcell.Sector infosector, vcell.Channel infochannel,
         vcell.physical_cell_id infopci, vcell.TAC infotac, 
         tbl.* 
     from
         cim.v_zone v_zone,cim.v_cluster v_cluster, 
         cim.v_territory v_territory, cim.v_location v_location,
         cim.v_cell_lte vcell, netact_b_lnd.SRAN_CELL_LNCEL tbl 
     where
         v_zone.zone_label = '9'  
         and v_location.operator_name = 'Base' 
         and vcell.operator_name = 'Box' 
         and vcell.vendor_name = 'N' 
         and v_zone.zone_id = v_cluster.zone_id 
         and v_territory.territory_id = v_zone.territory_id 
         and v_cluster.cluster_id = v_location.cluster_id 
         and vcell.engineering_number = v_location.engineering_number 
         and SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNBTS-',1) + 6, 6) = vcell.enodeb_id
         and REPLACE(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, INSTR(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME || '/', INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, 4),'/',1)),'/','') = vcell.local_cell_id 
       order by tbl.distname) tablea  
where 
    ROWNUM <= 5

I was following this page to do pagination on Oracle database.
https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/on-rownum-and-limiting-results
Here is a simlar query that work with pagination I built
 select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( SELECT vcell.operator_name as Provider, vcell.vendor_name as Vendor, loc.region_id as Region, loc.zone_short_name AS Zone, loc.clust, vcell.engineering_number, loc.loc_site_long_nm AS Name, vcell.Band, vcell.Freq_Band, vcell.Carrier,    
vcell.NRARFCN_DL, vcell.BANDWIDTH_MHZ_DL, vcell.NRARFCN_UL, vcell.BANDWIDTH_MHZ_UL, vcell.cell_type, vcell.gnodeb_id as GNODEBID, vcell.local_cell_id as LOCALCELLID, vcell.cell_name as LOCALCELLNAME, vcell.Sector, vcell.PHYSICALCELLID, vcell.TAC, tbl.* 
FROM netact_b_lnd.SRAN_NRC_NRCELL tbl 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT vcl.gnodeb_id, vcl.cell_id, vcl.cell_name, vcl.engineering_number, vcl.operator_name, vcl.vendor_name, vcl.local_cell_id, vcl.NRDUCELLID, vcl.PHYSICALCELLID, vcl.cell_type, vcl.nci, vcl.sector, vcl.band, vcl.carrier, vcl.freq_band, vcl.TAC,  vcl.NRARFCN_DL, vcl.BANDWIDTH_MHZ_DL,
vcl.NRARFCN_UL, vcl.BANDWIDTH_MHZ_UL FROM cim.v_cell_nr vcl WHERE vcl.operator_name = 'Base' and vcl.vendor_name = 'N') vcell 
ON SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'MRBTS-',1) + 6, 7) = vcell.gnodeb_id AND REPLACE(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'NRCELL-',1) + 7, INSTR(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME || '/', INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'NRCELL-',1) + 7, 4),'/',1)),'/','') = vcell.local_cell_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT v_location.engineering_number, v_location.loc_site_long_nm, v_location.operator_name, v_cluster.region_id, v_zone.zone_short_name, v_cluster.cluster_nm AS clust, v_location.province, v_location.region FROM cim.v_zone v_zone 
INNER JOIN cim.v_cluster v_cluster ON v_zone.zone_id = v_cluster.zone_id 
INNER JOIN cim.v_location v_location ON v_cluster.cluster_id = v_location.cluster_id 
WHERE v_location.operator_name = 'Box') loc ON vcell.engineering_number = loc.engineering_number order BY tbl.distname ) a 
      where ROWNUM < 200000 ) 
where rnum  >= 1


Bad habits to kick: using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years ago!) and its use is discouraged

Use FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY instead of ROWNUM <= 5.

That old join syntax is from the SQL-89... the "lambada year".

I do have another query with Inner joins it looks messy to share with here multiple table joins. I don't think that is the issue here

these two join conditions are also very likely not making good usage of indexes: and SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNBTS-',1) + 6, 6) = vcell.enodeb_id          and REPLACE(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, 'LNCEL-', 1) + 6, INSTR(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME || '/', INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, 4),'/',1)),'/','') = vcell.local_cell_id

You should run an execution plan of your query and start there.

Apart from what you've been told in comments, did you try to use row_number analytic function? Use your current query as a CTE for better readability (instead of an inline view you used).
with tablea as
    (select
         row_number() over (order by tbl.distname) rn,
         --
         vcell.operator_name, vcell.vendor_name, 
         v_territory.territory_label as Region, 
         v_zone.zone_short_name as Zone, v_cluster.cluster_nm, 
         vcell.engineering_number, v_location.loc_site_long_nm as Name,
         vcell.Band infoband, vcell.Freq_Band infofreqband, 
         vcell.Carrier infocarr,vcell.channel_bandwidth infobandwidth, 
         vcell.cell_type infocelltype, vcell.enodeb_id infoenbid, 
         vcell.local_cell_id infocellid,vcell.ecell_name infocellname,
         vcell.Sector infosector, vcell.Channel infochannel,
         vcell.physical_cell_id infopci, vcell.TAC infotac, 
         tbl.* 
     from
         cim.v_zone v_zone,cim.v_cluster v_cluster, 
         cim.v_territory v_territory, cim.v_location v_location,
         cim.v_cell_lte vcell, netact_b_lnd.SRAN_CELL_LNCEL tbl 
     where
         v_zone.zone_label = '9'  
         and v_location.operator_name = 'Base' 
         and vcell.operator_name = 'Box' 
         and vcell.vendor_name = 'N' 
         and v_zone.zone_id = v_cluster.zone_id 
         and v_territory.territory_id = v_zone.territory_id 
         and v_cluster.cluster_id = v_location.cluster_id 
         and vcell.engineering_number = v_location.engineering_number 
         and SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNBTS-',1) + 6, 6) = vcell.enodeb_id
         and REPLACE(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME, INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, INSTR(SUBSTR(tbl.DISTNAME || '/', INSTR(tbl.DISTNAME,'LNCEL-',1) + 6, 4),'/',1)),'/','') = vcell.local_cell_id 
      ) 
select *
from tablea
where rn <= 5
order by rn;


Its the same result query just stuck there with out sending any results. adding any ROWNUM column seem to break this query. maybe the table is too big to sort by ROWNUM. It has a lot of columns.
